# Parse push notifications don't appear on notification tray on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, ionic-framework

I have an Android app developed with [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/). I'm using the [ngCordova plugin for push notifications](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/) and sending them using parse.com

The notifications are received when the app is running, but the notifications are not shown on the notification tray when the app is on background. I receive something like this:

```
notification = {
  payload: {
    data: {
      alert: "message",
    }
  }
}
```

But, when I send them directly through CGM, the notification do appear on the notification tray. And the object I receive is like:

```
notification = {
  message: "this appear on notification tray",
  payload: {
     message: "this appear on notification tray"
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with Parse? Or is something I'm missing about Parse?

Comment: Hey, can you please share your code (The way you set up Parse push notification using ngCordova)

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an old post, but I ran across this issue using *Xamarin* and Parse Push notifications, but my work around may work for you (and others that may see this in the future).

I wound up broadcasting a local Push Notification after the Parse notification is received.

First assign a receiver to the Parse notification event:

```
ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += PushNotificationReceived;
```

Then in the method:

```
void PushNotificationReceived (object sender, ParsePushNotificationEventArgs e)
{
     var payload = JObject.Parse (e.StringPayload); // Parse the JSON payload

     Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder (this);
     builder.SetContentTitle (payload ["alert"].ToString ());
     builder.SetContentText (payload ["androidDetail"].ToString ()); // Note: this is another field I added to the Parse Notification
     builder.SetDefaults (NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);
     builder.SetSound (RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri (RingtoneType.Notification));
     builder.SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.small_notification_icon);

     var largeIcon = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource (Resources, Resource.Drawable.large_notification_icon);
     builder.SetLargeIcon (largeIcon);

     var notification = builder.Build ();
     notification.Defaults |= NotificationDefaults.Vibrate;

     NotificationManager notManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService (Context.NotificationService);

     notManager.Notify (0, notification);
}
```

Hope this helps you and anyone else who comes across this!